# How to pass "ID" instead of name/value from jsp to servlet?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp, servlets

I am working with JSP and servlet and I have a checkbox in which I have lot of items, each item has a name and id along with its value. These items are getting populated dynamically.

Now I need to return whatever items I am selecting back to jsp page. As of now, I am able to return the value of all those items which I have selected to jsp page.

Below is my code:

**JQuery code**

Below code populates dynamically the checkbox list -

```
$(document).ready(function () {                           
    $('.btn-secondary').click(function () {                  
        $('.btn-secondary').removeClass('currentButton')
        $(this).addClass('currentButton')
        $('form').hide()
        $("#form_" + $(this).attr('id')).show()
        $.get('/adataservlet', function (responseJson) {
            var $input = $('#id2');
            var $type = 'checkbox';
            $.each(responseJson, function (key, value) {
                var append = $('<input name="meta" type="' + $type + '">' + value + '</input>').attr('id', key).val(value);
                $($input).append('<br/>').append(append);
            });
        });

    });
});
```

**JSP code**

```
<p>
<input type="button" class="btn-secondary" id="prof" value="Create Profile"/>
</p>

<form id="form_prof" method="post" action="/adataservlet/">
   <div id="id2" name="id2" class="container"></div>
   <div class="line submit"><input type="submit" value="Create"/></div>
   <input type='hidden' name='action' value='create'>
</form>
```

**Servlet code**
In my below servlet code, I am extracting all the values which I have selected in the checkbox as soon as I click create button and it works fine.

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {

    // return list of values I have selected
    String[] reports = request.getParameterValues("meta");
    System.out.println(reports);

}
```

But is there any way to get the list of id's instead of list of values whatever I am selecting? Since the above code will return the list of values whatever I have selected?

Is this possible to do?

Comment: use the ID's as values

Comment: @Dr.Molle, Is there any other way? I have value and id different :(

Comment: I don't think there is a direct way out there. You may want to put the id value in another hidden input as a 'value'.